How can i update AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion in a file using az cli?
I have an assembly file and i want to update the number in AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion. for example in the file AssemblyInfo.cs  down the bottom is
  [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.1")]
  [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.0.1")]    

how can i update this to
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.1.2.5")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.1.2.5")]
using the az cli cmdlets ?

You might need to give some more context for your question - for example, why are you trying to use the az cli specifically (as opposed to some other tool) to edit the contents of a file? Note that if this is part of a CI pipeline you can provide values for those specific attributes as parameters on the msbuild or "dotnet build" command line, so you may not even need to edit the files themselves in the first place to generate assemblies with the desired version numbers burned into them...
